# TCLAP issus with parsing std::wstring

Tags: c++

TCLAP `std::wstring` issue. 
Hello All,

I am using TCLAP(command line parsing utility). It has worked well so far until I ran into issues with wstring processing capability.

I have the below line to parse code for an UnlabeledValueArg

```
std::wstring defaultValue; 

UnlabeledValueArg<std::wstring>
serverName("COMPUTERNAME", "List all scheduled tasks of computer", false,
           defaultValue, "string" );
```

I run into compile time issues ( Visual Studio spits out incredulous amounts of issues.). My question is have anyone tried using std::wstring with TCLAP. If yes can you post the solution or the approach to it. Thanks.

Edit - The compiler warnings I get is -

> C:\DevProjects\MyProjects\nttoolkit\trunk\external\tclap/StandardTraits.h(187)
>   : error C2679: binary '=' : no
>   operator found which takes a
>   right-hand operand of type 'const
>   std::string' (or there is no
>   acceptable conversion)
>
> ```
>     c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> ```
>
> 9.0\VC\include\xstring(914): could be 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>
>
> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator
>
> =(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>
>   &)'
>           with
>           [
>               _Elem=wchar_t,
>               _Traits=std::char_traits,
>               _Ax=std::allocator
>           ]
>
> ```
>     c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> ```
>
> 9.0\VC\include\xstring(919): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>
>   &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator
>   =(const _Elem *)'
>           with
>           [
>               _Elem=wchar_t,
>               _Traits=std::char_traits,
>               _Ax=std::allocator
>           ]
>
> ```
>     c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
> ```
>
> 9.0\VC\include\xstring(924): or       'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>
>   &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Ax>::operator
>   =(_Elem)'
>           with
>           [
>               _Elem=wchar_t,
>               _Traits=std::char_traits,
>               _Ax=std::allocator
>           ]
>           while trying to match the argument list '(std::wstring, const
>   std::string)'
>
> ```
>     C:\DevProjects\MyProjects\nttoolkit\trunk\external\tclap/Arg.h(446)
> ```
>
> : see reference to function template
>   instantiation 'void
>   TCLAP::SetString(T &,const
>   std::string &)' being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               T=std::wstring
>           ]
>
> ```
>     C:\DevProjects\MyProjects\nttoolkit\trunk\external\tclap/ValueArg.h(391)
> ```
>
> : see reference to function template
>   instantiation 'void
>   TCLAP::ExtractValue(T &,const
>   std::string &,TCLAP::StringLike)'
>   being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               T=std::wstring
>           ]
>
> ```
>     C:\DevProjects\MyProjects\nttoolkit\trunk\external\tclap/ValueArg.h(389)
> ```
>
> : while compiling class template
>   member function 'void
>   TCLAP::ValueArg::_extractValue(const
>   std::string &)'
>           with
>           [
>               T=std::wstring
>           ]
>
> ```
>     C:\DevProjects\MyProjects\nttoolkit\trunk\external\tclap/ValueArg.h(325)
> ```
>
> : while compiling class template
>   member function 'bool
>   TCLAP::ValueArg::processArg(int
>   *,std::vector<_Ty> &)'
>           with
>           [
>               T=std::wstring,
>               _Ty=std::string
>           ]
>
> ```
>     C:\DevProjects\MyProjects\nttoolkit\trunk\external\tclap/UnlabeledValueArg.h(44)
> ```
>
> : see reference to class template
>
> instantiation 'TCLAP::ValueArg'
>   being compiled
>           with
>           [
>               T=std::wstring
>           ]
>
> ```
>     C:\DevProjects\MyProjects\nttoolkit\trunk\tasksecure\src\main.cpp(26)
> ```
>
> : see reference to class template
>   instantiation
>   'TCLAP::UnlabeledValueArg' being
>   compiled
>           with
>           [
>               T=std::wstring
>           ]
>
> TaskSecure - 1 error(s), 6 warning(s)

Comment: What are the errors VS is giving you?

Comment: I've just edited and added the compiler warnings. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the source and built your example. The UnlabeledValueArg does take std::string, so apologies. The StandardTraits.h:202 shows dst = src. It is trying to set std::string to a std::wstring and there is no conversion. Apparently, TCLAP does not support std::wstring. The src should be std::wstring.

One work around might be to use std::string instead, and UTF-8 encode your program's arguments before using TCLAP.

Another option is to ask the owner of TCLAP to extend it to support either wide and narrow arguments.

Comment: When in doubt kindly add it as a comment. Also try having a look at the method signature before posting replies.

Comment: @Eternal Learner - the method signature indicates: no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const std::string'.  To me, that looks like you should be using wide strings.

Comment: Maybe having a look at this might give you a better idea. - http://tclap.sourceforge.net/html/annotated.html . Have a look at the UnlabeledValueArg class constructor.

Comment: @Eternal Learner - I downloaded the source and built your example.  The UnlabeledValueArg does take std::string, so apologies.  The StandardTraits.h:202 shows `dst = src`.  It is trying to set std::string to a std::wstring and there is no conversion.  Apparently, TCLAP does not support std::wstring.  The `src` should be std::wstring.  A work around might be to use std::string instead, and UTF-8 encode your program's arguments before using TCLAP.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Yes I am looking into that now and trying to add support to std::wstring.  I don't know much about UTF-8 encoding. Thanks will look into it. Kindly edit your answer so that I can remove my down-vote(thanks for taking time off and undergoing the pain of downloading the source).

Answer (score 1):

I also had a problem with TCLAP trying to process Unicode in command lines. I solved it by modifying TCLAP to use wchar_t and std::wstring. So I've made WTCLAP (Wide Templatized Command Line Argument Parser - https://github.com/vasyutin/wtclap). Maybe it will be useful for you, too. You can even use TCLAP and WTCLAP together in platform independent code.